# How to initialize a list from a database (sqflite)

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

i get a `Future<List<Sentence>>`(Sentence is a class with int id and String sentence) returned by the sqflite function `getSentences`. Now i want that List in my main widget tree. therefore i created this function:

```dart
 Future<void> initializeSentences() async {
    sentences = await getSentences();
  }
```

and it badically does what i need. When the Function is executed, my list `sentences` gets filled with the Sentences from the database. But the problem is, i dont know where to call the function.

I already tried it in `initState()` and below `Widget build(BuildContext context) {` but if i start the app, i always need to do something that triggers `setState()` to see the loaded list.

How can i initialize that list right at the start of the app, and also show it ?

Comment: Are you using statless widget or stateful widget?

Comment: im using stateful widget

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Stateless` widget you should initialize the values via constructor like below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> sentences;

  const MyApp({Key key, this.sentences}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [Text(sentences[0]), Text(sentences[1])],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you are using `StatefullWidget` then you should initialize via `initState()` method or use `FutureBuilder()` like below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future<String> _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => 'Data Loaded',
  );

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            children = <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.check_circle_outline,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
              )
            ];
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = <Widget>[
              Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              )
            ];
          } else {
            children = <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              )
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in my case its a statefull widget, but i cant initialize it like this, because i need to use an async await function. My `getSentences()` function returns a ´Future<List<Sentences>>´ and to loose the future i need to await `getSentences`

Comment: Then while building your widget, you have to use kind of Futurebuilder

Comment: ahh yea okay, the problem is i dont unterstand how to use that.
But then i will try to lern it now

Comment: I have updated the code with FutureBuilder. Please refer.

Comment: Nice! This looks very helpfull, but i need some time to go trough it, thanks very much!